# jQuery slideUp() not shrinking padding-bottom value

Tags: jquery, css

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wPad/1/), you'll notice when you click one of the buttons, the container will slowly slide up. When it gets to the top, you will see that it doesn't quite slide up all the way. If you look in the inspector, the `li`'s bottom padding is not shrinking as you might expect it do during a `slideUp()` operation.

Any idea why?

Note: the slide up is so slow to better display the problem.

Note 2: When I change the jQuery library to 1.7.2 it actually works correctly. Interesting.

FWIW: I filed a [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12416) with jQuery

Comment: Seems like yet another regression on 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This regression was fixed in jQuery 1.8.1 - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9wPad/14/).

---

As you've already noticed, this is another bug in v1.8.0.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UmTds/1/) demonstrates that the `paddingBottom` is simply subtracted at very end of the `slideUp`'s animation. The subtle `paddingBottom` subtraction is not visible on your fiddle because when you call `slideDown` inside the callback, the `paddingBottom` is added back instantly (symetrically to how it was subtracted). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UmTds/2/)

if you don't want to wait until the fix is released and don't want to downgrade to 1.7.2, a temporary workaround to make it behave as 1.7.2 would is to pass the CSS properties map to `.animate`:

```
function next() {
    var q = $(this).parents('li');
    q.data('originalDimensions', {
        borderTopWidth: q.css('borderTopWidth'),
        paddingTop: q.css('paddingTop'),
        height: q.css('height'),
        paddingBottom: q.css('paddingBottom'),
        borderBottomWidth: q.css('borderBottomWidth')
    });
    q.animate({ borderTopWidth:0, paddingTop:0, height:0, paddingBottom:0, borderBottomWidth:0 }, 5000, function(){
        $(this).animate($(this).data('originalDimensions'), 5000);
    });
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9wPad/6/)

Let's vote up your ticket and hope it gets fixed in the 1.8.1 release.

**edit**: Updated the workaround to store the `originalDimensions` in the element's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), this way it can be used at a later time and in a different scope. To animate multiple elements at a time, use `.each` iteration for setting the `.data()`:

```
q.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('originalDimensions', {
        borderTopWidth: $this.css('borderTopWidth'),
        //...
    });
});
q.animate({ borderTopWidth:0, /*...*/ }, 5000, function() {
    $(this).animate($(this).data('originalDimensions'), 5000);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9wPad/13/)